# raw pointer assignment to std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a function which decodes the base64 string an returns a unsigned char* pointer.

```
unsigned char* Base64Decode(const StdString& a_strStdBase64, int& len);
```

I need to assign the returned pointer to a unique_ptr to make the remaining code memory leak safe from exception.

```
void doSomething()
{
 unsigned char *sDecodedText =  Base64Decode(...);
 std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> upDecodedText(sDecodedText);
 // Will use the decoded text here in other part implementations
}
```

This compiles fine but throws exception when upDecodedText goes out of scope. I understand that unique_ptr can only free the memory which is allocated by it. In the sense, Like below

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> upDecodedText(new unsigned char[10]);
```

Is my approach for making the code memory leak safe? Suggestions for modifications are welcome

EDIT:: Base64Decode Implementation

```
unsigned char*
Base64Decode(const StdString& a_strStdBase64, // Base64-encoded string
             int& len,                        // resulting decoded buffer length
             bool bUrlSafe)                   // URL safe
{
    if (a_strStdBase64.empty())
    {
      return NULL;
    }

    int inDataLen = (int) len;

    // Since Base64-encoded string is an ASCII string, do simple conversion.
    const std::string strBase64(a_strStdBase64.begin(), a_strStdBase64.end());
    const char* bufcoded = strBase64.c_str();

    unsigned char* bufplain = new unsigned char[inDataLen];
    if (NULL == bufplain)
    {
       return NULL;
    }

    //int base64Decode(int mode, const char* pInData, int nInDataLen, unsigned char* pOutData, int* pnOutDataLen)
    if(base64Decode(BASE64_MODE_DEFAULT, bufcoded, inDataLen , bufplain, &len) != BASE64_SUCCESS)
    {
        delete [] bufplain;
        return NULL;
    }

    return bufplain;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing how `Base64Decode()` is implemented, it will be difficult to answer this. In particular, where does it's return value get its memory from?

Comment: How does `Base64Decode` allocate memory? If it's anything other than `new char[]`, then the default deleter will do the wrong thing, so you'll need a custom deleter to do the right thing.

Comment: You seem to be confused about your own code. Is it `char *` or `unsigned char *`? The code *looks* OK, but since it seems to be half-remembered/half-invented code, it's perfectly possible that your real code is full of eels.

Comment: Are there any DLLs involved here, or multiple compiler versions?

Comment: `Base64Decode()` should return `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointer as well.

Comment: Just needed an idea about memory allocation and free. So I omitted unsigned in my explanation. Made an edit to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are overflowing your buffer.  The comments indicate that `len` is supposed to be an *output* parameter yielding the size of the resulting data, but you're using its *input* value to size your array.

Result: the allocated buffer has an unknown size, perhaps zero, and the results don't fit, so they overwrite metadata stored adjacent to the allocated buffer, causing a later failure in memory allocation and deallocation functions.

Answer (score 0):

using `unsigned char*` as return value could work on some hardware fx. core i5, however you could run into issues on hardware fx. core i7 -- so I suggest using `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char>` instead of `unsigned char*`